# plot names of columns in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a subset of my dataset:

```
structure(list(zone = c(3L, 4L, 2L), la3 = c(1, 
6, 3), la4 = c(3, -2, 5)), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "data.frame")
```

How I can plot (ggplot2) them as the names of columns  (la3 and la4)on x axis and zone on y axis?

Comment: Do you want a dot plot with both la3 and la4 on it ? Or 2 separate plots ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform your data to "long" format first if you want to plot `la3` and `la4` on the same plot. You can add labels using `geom_text` or `geom_label`, but I highly recommend using the package `ggrepel` to add labels to a plot, and the functions `geom_text_repel` or `geom_label_repel`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

ggplot(data %>% gather(key=la, ...=-zone)) + 
geom_point(aes(la, value, color=as.character(zone))) +
geom_text_repel(aes(la, value, label=zone))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain more precisely please ?

Comment: it will be like this: geom_point(aes(la, value,color= zone)) , but the problem the color will be continued not discrete for each zone, any idea?

Comment: There you go. You need to cast "zone" as a character or a factor.